# Git 'pull' priorities

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull

I'd like to have some sort of 'priorities' in a git pull. Take the below folder structure.

- Root
- - global
- - host1.domain.com
- - host2.domain.com

If host1.domain.com does a pull, it should pull from both global AND host1.domain.com to the same folder (I'm thinking two separate pull's?).

How can I make git have priorities that if the same file exists in global AND host1.domain.com repo's take priority over the host1.domain.com repo?

If I pull from global first, then host1, will it overwrite files?

Comment: Do you want that the same file will be tracked in two different repositories? why?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Please make sure to ask about what you are actually trying to accomplish, not what you think the solution might be.

Comment: BTW checkout the submodule capability of git, maybe that's what you are looking for.. (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)